# Meaning of `penalty` and `loss` in LinearSVC

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, liblinear

**Anti-closing preamble:** I have read the question "[difference between penalty and loss parameters in Sklearn LinearSVC library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042909/difference-between-penalty-and-loss-parameters-in-sklearn-linearsvc-library)" but I find the answer there not to be specific enough. Therefore, I’m reformulating the question:

I *am* familiar with SVM theory and I’m experimenting with LinearSVC class in Python. However, the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC) is not quite clear regarding the meaning of `penalty` and `loss` parameters. I recon that `loss` refers to the penalty for points violating the margin (usually denoted by the Greek letter *xi* or *zeta* in the objective function), while `penalty` is the norm of the vector determining the class boundary, usually denoted by ***w***. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

If my guess is right, then `penalty = 'l1'` would lead to minimisation of the *L1*-norm of the vector ***w***, like in LASSO regression. How does this relate to the maximum-margin idea of the SVM? Can anyone point me to a publication regarding this question? In the [original paper describing LIBLINEAR](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf) I could not find any reference to *L1* penalty.

Also, if my guess is right, why doesn't LinearSVC support the combination of `penalty='l2'` and `loss='hinge'` (the standard combination in [SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-mathematical-formulation)) when `dual=False`? When trying it, I get the

> ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though very late, I'll try to give my answer. According to the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#linearsvc), here's the considered primal optimization problem for `LinearSVC`:
[image],`phi` being the Identity matrix, given that `LinearSVC` only solves linear  problems.

Effectively, this is just one of the possible problems that `LinearSVC` admits (it is the *L2-regularized*, *L1-loss* in the terms of the LIBLINEAR paper) and not the default one (which is the *L2-regularized*, *L2-loss*).
The LIBLINEAR paper gives a more general formulation for what concerns what's referred to as `loss` in Chapter 2, then it further elaborates also on what's referred to as `penalty` within the Appendix (A2+A4).

Basically, it states that LIBLINEAR is meant to solve the following unconstrained optimization pb with different `loss` functions `xi(w;x,y)` (which are `hinge` and `squared_hinge`); the default setting of the model in LIBLINEAR does not consider the bias term, that's why you won't see any reference to `b` from now on (there are many posts on SO on this).

- [image], `hinge` or *L1-loss*
- [image], `squared_hinge` or *L2-loss*.

For what concerns the `penalty`, basically this represents the norm of the vector `w` used. The appendix elaborates on the different problems:

- *L2-regularized*, *L1-loss* (`penalty='l2'`, `loss='hinge'`): [image]
- *L2-regularized*, *L2-loss* (`penalty='l2'`, `loss='squared_hinge'`), default in `LinearSVC`:[image]
- *L1-regularized*, *L2-loss* (`penalty='l1'`, `loss='squared_hinge'`):[image]

Instead, as stated within the documentation, `LinearSVC` does not support the combination of `penalty='l1'` and `loss='hinge'`. As far as I see the paper does not specify why, but I found a possible answer [here](https://www.quora.com/Liblinear-does-not-support-L1-regularized-L1-loss-hinge-loss-support-vector-classification-Why) (within the answer by Arun Iyer).

Eventually, effectively the combination of `penalty='l2'`, `loss='hinge'`, `dual=False` is not supported as specified in [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7714) (it is just not implemented in LIBLINEAR) or [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9521f79b29a3d995bf2b25a4ba13aed87fe0587d/sklearn/svm/tests/test_svm.py#L783); not sure whether that's the case, but within the LIBLINEAR paper from Appendix B onwards it is specified the optimization pb that's solved (which in the case of *L2-regularized*, *L1-loss* seems to be the dual).

For a theoretical discussion on SVC pbs in general, I found [that chapter](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes3.pdf) really useful; it shows how the minimization of the norm of `w` relates to the idea of the maximum-margin.